# Insert через процедуру большого количества строк из CSV

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация, plsql

Есть задача загрузки CSV файла через Web интерфейс. Во время загрузки на стороне клиента выполняются проверки на корректность данных в файле.
Сейчас мы вставляем миллионы строк вызывая процедуру вставки одной строки.
То есть, для каждой строки файла вызывается процедура.

Схематичный вид процедуры:

```
procedure example(iValue1 IN Table.column1,
                  iValue2 IN Table.column2,
                  iValue3 IN Table.column3) is
begin
  insert into table(column1, column2, column3) values (iValue1, iValue3, iValue3);
end;
```

Вызов миллионов раз это процедуры работает непозволительно медленно. Как можно изменить подход для ускорения процесса вставки?

Comment: Вызываете откуда ? Там используются подготовленные запросы и одна компиляция запроса и в цикле вызов только исполнения с новыми значениями ? И зачем вообще придумана эта процедура, вызов непосредственно insert был бы быстрее

Comment: Это загрузка csv файла через приложение. И для каждой строки csv фала вызывается процедура.

Comment: csv было бы гораздо быстрее грузить с помощью sql*loader

Comment: На стороне клиента выполняются некоторые проверки, на валидность данных в `csv`. Напрямую sql*loader использовать не получается. Кажется, что можно попробовать передавать и грузить коллекциями, но не очень понятно, как.

Comment: перенести проверки можно в триггере, отбракованные записи sql*loader отложит в отдельный файл. Так а почему же все таки процедура, а не прямой вызов insert, чем это продиктовано ?

Comment: Похоже, что так исторически сложилось. Сейчас есть набор пакетов для работы с БД и все взаимодействие с БД осуществляется через эти пакеты.

Comment: ну ускорение требует жертв :) делайте по крайней мере прямой insert, если не достаточно, переделывайте на merge с загрузкой нескольких записей одновременно. Если и это медленно читайте входной файл, делайте свои проверки и те строки что надо грузить через стандартный ввод подавайте запущенному sql*loader'у

Comment: "Напрямую sql*loader использовать не получается" - а почему, какие основания (доп. вопрос - что значит напрямую)? Тот же вопрос про внешние таблицы, вроде  в вопросе и комментариях к нему они не упоминаются, а в принятом ответе "если нет возможности воспользоваться".

Comment: "На прямую" - это значит сразу загрузить в целевую таблицу. Пока в тестовом варианте принято решение попробовать грузить все sql*loadr'ом в отдельную таблицу, а всю логику и валидацию выполнить используя хранимую процедуру на PL\SQL.

Comment: А, понятно, на прямую никто не делает, грузится в stage, валидируется и тогда уже в целевуя таблицу, merge самое оптимальное. И посмотрите ещё внешние таблицы, есть плюсы/минусы, но тоже вариант.

Comment: А проверки данных вы можете делать в самом запросе выбора этих данных? Что именно там проверяется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нет возможности воспользоваться [SQL*loader](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SUTIL/oracle-sql-loader-commands.htm#SUTIL004) или [`insert from External Table`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SUTIL/oracle-external-tables-concepts.htm#SUTIL011), то можно попробовать использовать [bulk insert](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/news_plsql_forall_performance_insert.htm):

```
DECLARE
TYPE prod_tab IS TABLE OF products%ROWTYPE;
products_tab   prod_tab := prod_tab();
start_time  number;  end_time   number;
BEGIN
-- Populate a collection - 100000 rows
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO products_tab FROM products;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE products';
Start_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
FOR i in products_tab.first .. products_tab.last LOOP
 INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name, effective_date)
   VALUES (products_tab(i).product_id, products_tab(i).product_name,
           products_tab(i).effective_date);
END LOOP;
end_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Conventional Insert: ’||to_char(end_time-start_time));

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE products';
Start_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
FORALL i in products_tab.first .. products_tab.last
 INSERT INTO products VALUES products_tab(i);
end_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Bulk Insert: ’||to_char(end_time-start_time));
COMMIT;
END;
```

[Примеры использования BULK COLLECT и FORALL...](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html)

Answer (score 3):

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731477/insert-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-oracle?rq=1#comment1110422_731477):

> Кажется, что можно попробовать передавать и грузить коллекциями, но не очень понятно, как.

Идея не лишена смысла - заполняйте коллекцию и передавайте её как параметр. Вот так:

```sql
create table prodtab (col1 number, col2 number, col3 number)
/
create or replace type csvRow as object (val1 number, val2 number, val3 number)
/
create or replace type csvRows as table of csvRow
/
create or replace procedure importCsv (rows csvRows) is
begin 
    insert into prodtab 
        select * from table (rows);
    dbms_output.put_line (sql%rowcount||' rows inserted.');
end;
/
```

Попробовать и результат:

```sql
exec importCsv (csvRows (csvRow (1,2,3), csvRow (4,5,6), csvRow (7,8,9)))
```

> 3 rows inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что при использовании процедуры у вас постоянно переключается контекст с PL/SQL на SQL, это затратная операция.

Тут могут быть только два варианта оптимизации:

1. Самый быстрый, если данные можно запросить из таблицы:

```sql
insert into Table1 (column1, column2, column3)
select iValue1, iValue2, iValue3
from Table2;
```

2. Если без процедуры ни как, то проверьте, возможно commit делается после каждого вызова `example`, нужно вызывать его один раз после вставки всех строк.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Это загрузка файла и нет возможности сделать `insert .. select ..`. `Commit` выполняется в конце загрузки